# data exporting with MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I'm trying to export a schema/DB out of mysql and I'm getting a weird error.

I also ran several grant commands (see below) which I believe should be enough to let me export the data. On MySQLWorkbench, I logged in as a user mentioned in the grand commands.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks a lot

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception: Error querying security information: Error executing 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='mydb' AND Host='myhost.com' ORDER BY User, Host'
SELECT command denied to user 'mydb'@'my-ip-here' for table 'user'.
SQL Error: 1142
```

**grant commands:**

```
mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'mydb'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> grant show databases on *.* to 'mydb'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'mydb'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mydb@%                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypassword' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'mydb'@'%'                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I can see in error message that is permission issue only for table 'user' so you should check that you have privileges for user table to export?........Try this GRANT SELECT ON mydb.user TO 'mydb'@'localhost';